# Was my upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 successful?

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded without problem from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 17.04.
The MenuFunction "About This computer" still shows "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS".

Is this normal?

```
seppe@win7:~$ uname -a
Linux win7 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

seppe@win7:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Open a terminal by pressing `CTRL+ALT+T` and type:  `uname -a`[Enter]. Then type: `lsb_release -a`[Enter]. Then copy the output in the terminal. Then [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/953361/edit) your question and paste the copied output.

Comment: How did you upgrade ?

Comment: googlesearch for "upgrade to ubuntu 17.04To upgrade on a desktop system:"
1. Open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Settings.
2. Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".
3. Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version".
4. Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager -c" (without the quotes) into the command box.